# live-build / lb config help needed

Tags: grub-efi

Hi I'm trying to build custom iso for my asus t100ta wich is uefi only

My goal is to make it bootable grub-efi 32bit

My question is how do I specify mainline kernel=>(3.16) and grub-efi bootable?

here is my example:

```
lb config --bootloader grub-efi -d utopic -a i386 --win32-loader false --mode ubuntu --archive-areas "main restricted universe multiverse" --memtest memtest86+ --debian-installer true --debian-installer-gui true ­­--apt­recommends true
```

summery:

```
grub-efi /32 bit
mainline kernel /32 bit
unity
```

Please help me to correct it

Thank you.